# Can Android's internal memory be mapped to a drive letter on PC?

Tags: android

When an Android device is plugged in to a PC (through USB?), is the internal file system mapped to a drive letter on the PC? So that one can copy files to and from the Android under Windows?

And, can Emulator simulate the situation when it's plugged in? How?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Almost all of the answers here talk about the so-called "External" storage, even in it's permanently installed and/or emulated implementations.  Ultimately it should be possible to expose any internal and/or external files *which a 3rd party application can access* over a network-filesystem type mechanism, using for a known implemented example ssh (with sshfs) or possibly SMB using some sort of port of SAMBA code.

Comment: Well, as they say, time passes and I thought [this](https://www.guidingtech.com/39472/map-android-drive-windows/) might be of interest.  It might only provide access to the sd card though, I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mount the device via USB but (in Win7 at least) it doesn't appear to have its own drive letter; rather it's treated like a camera or another media device. It doesn't mount automatically; you generally need to "opt-in" in the notification area with something like "Turn on USB storage"

Don't know about emulators.

Comment: Except for devices without a MicroSD card (i.e., Nexus S), turning on USB storage will mount the card as a drive letter in Windows. I think the question refers to the internal memory of the phone, not the MicroSD card

Comment: @sargas @cheezmeister Thank you! So I gather the answer is "no" for internal memory. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Right, AFAIK. Although you can still use 'adb push'/'adb pull'

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it CAN be mapped to a drive letter.  It was much easier with something like a Droid X (Android 2.3), since it would show up as a mass storage device (disconnecting the card from your phone in the meantime), but it's also possible on newer phones such as the LG G3 if you're willing to install 2 free programs, which you probably would like to have anyway.

**ES File Explorer - Remote Manager (FTP Server)**

First, you need a file manager, not only because the built-in one is useless, but also because you need an FTP server.  Install "ES File Explorer" on your Android Device.  Then in the options, turn on the "Remote Manager" option, which will activate the FTP server and show you its local address like "192.168.1.3:3721.  You can now access your phone as an FTP site from your computer when on your local WiFi network.

[image: ES File Explorer - Remote Manager (FTP Server)]

**Net Drive - Remote Drive Mapping Utility**

Next, all you have to do is install NetDrive: http://netdrive.net/  It's freeware and seems to be used by a lot of companies, because it lets you map cloud storage to local drives.  That will allow you to map your FTP server on your phone as a local drive.

[image: Net Drive]

Don't bother trying to map an FTP site with explorer.  First, you may run into a problem that's apparently caused by Chrome, where you can't even add an FTP network location.  You'll get an unexpected error telling you the path format is invalid.  Interestingly, that is solved by opening the registry editor, then under [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftp] add a key named "ShellFolder" with string value "{E436EBB6-524F-11CE-9F53-0020AF0BA770}".  The error will immediately cease occurring, with no restart or any other action required.  Just go back in and add the ftp network location.  That, however, still does not allow you to map it to a drive letter, which is why you need NetDrive.

Comment: Works for me but only for the internal storage, on the SD card only a few directories are available, and I checked that those can be browsed fine with ES File Explorer (!?)

Comment: I don't recommend using NetDrive because you have to pay to be able to use it for more than a week.

Answer (score 8):

As of Android 4, [the wise ones](http://google.com) have removed USB Mass Storage support for accessing the internal phone memory. So you no-longer get direct block-access (or a driver letter in windows).  You can usually choose on the phone between MTP, or PTP (Media / Photo Transfer protocols) for whichever your OS supports better.

If your device has removable storage it should still support USBMS (with a drive letter) for that partition.  At least Android still supports that, but your Manufacturer or Carrier-ware may still fail you here.

However, when it comes to the phone memory, there was a [trade-off made in Honeycomb](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/18/impromptu-qa-session-with-android-engineer-dan-morrill-brings-to-light-reasons-behind-galaxy-nexus-lack-of-usb-mass-storage/). Unified storage prevents wasted space (no more separate storage for phone / data, and having one fill up first and having confused frustrated users trying to move apps to SD, etc). The trade-off requires that:

> Android can no longer ever yield up the storage for the host PC to
>   molest directly over USB.

Initially for Mac and Linux where support for MTP/PTP has been slower, You can use an FTP app on your phone.  But now there is an increasing number of Desktop (PC/Mac/**Linux**) apps that understand and support the MTP or PTP protocols.  You just don't get block access and so you can't get a drive letter without some hackery / third party software.

There have been hacks over the years to make FTP or WebDav or some other protocol work behind a windows drive letter, and something like could still work work for these MTP/PTP protocols, but I have yet to see any such consumer usable software for windows.

If your Linux distro doesn't include MTP support, [gMTP](http://gmtp.sourceforge.net/) seems pretty popular.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse you can push and pull files to the emulator using the DDMS perspective.  Doing similar on a real device, iirc will require root access to the device, at least to get to the 'sensitive' areas.

The SDK tools will also provide a way of push and pull via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

possible with https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win

difficult finding good sshservers for android, know that at least one works but doesn't autostart at wifi and have to manually restarted, which it was possible to "come home from work, drive is connected"

this server seams to work fine
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xnano.android.sshserver.tv&hl=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to backup(incremental) android device using Areca backup utility which requires src and dest to have drive paths.
After trying various methods like adb-sync, Syncthing, webDAV, etc. Got it working with ftp sharing.

1. Download any ftp server app. I used "[WiFi FTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.medhaapps.wififtpserver&hl=en_IN&gl=US)" by Medha Apps on Playstore to create a ftp server something like this- ftp://*username*:*@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy where username can be set in app settings and xxx is i.p. with yyyy as port number.
2. Map ftp URL to drive path by using free app- "[DirectNet Drive](http://www.directnet-drive.net/ftp.php)"

Use the drive as if it's in your own system, though it will be slow being wireless.